# Is it safe to move Desktop to D: Drive?

Tags: windows-11, desktop-customization, window-manager

Is it safe to move Desktop to D: Drive?

I found discordant opinions on the internet, but maybe it's because it depends on the computer, and how long you have been putting things into it. In my case, my computer is a brand new Huawei Matebook with Windows 11.

I moved Desktop to D: a few days ago, and I haven't had any problem yet, except that when I go to "This Pc" I don't get the Desktop folder any longer. Well, the folder is actually there, and the icon is the same, but instead of "Desktop" it's called "D:". And I can't find a way to name it "Desktop".

If that's the only problem I will ever get from moving Desktop to D: I'm fine with it, but I wanted to know if there may be other issues at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to move Desktop to D: Drive?

That depends on what is in your Desktop folder. The contents will differ by user.

Better (in my experience) to make a new folder Desktop or Desktop_1 on your second drive and then move contents (what will move and what makes sense) to the new Desktop folder on the other drive.

App shortcuts on your desktop (some System, some yours) take up very little space and should not be moved (especially System shortcuts).

Documents on your desktop and readily be moved.

Comment: I put Desktop back to C:, and now it's called "pictures" for some reason. I posted a new question about it. https://superuser.com/questions/1723632/why-is-desktop-now-called-pictures-after-moving-it-back-to-c

Comment: You should be able to make a new folder called Documents and put your pictures in that folder.