# Why is Desktop now called "Pictures" after moving it back to C:?

Tags: windows-11

[image]Why is Desktop now called "Pictures" after moving it back to C:?

My OS is windows 11.

I moved Desktop to D: by going to Properties, Location, Move, and I moved it to D: because it had more storage. Notice that I didn't put it in a folder, but  simply in D:.

But then I read from some people that this is not a safe thing to do as it might cause problems. For example, I noticed that my Desktop icon wasn't called Desktop anymore, but D:, and I couldn't find a way to rename it.

So, I decided to put it back by going to the desktop folder, clicking Properties, location, restore, and apply.

In terms of file destination everything is ok now, ie the files that were on the desktop now are gone becasue they are in D:, and D: is not my Desktop anymore. So that's fine.  But the desktop icon is named "Pictures" instead of "Desktop", even if the icon image is correct. Why did this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @DonaldDuck . I've just added it

Comment: What's the complete path of the Desktop folder?

Comment: @DonaldDuck It currently says "C:\Users\franc"

Comment: @Fra Is that its parent folder or the location of the folder itself?

Comment: @DonaldDuck. I don't know the difference, sorry. I just went to properties, location, and that's the location I read. By the way, in the meantime, I found out that If I move something to the folder "picture" (which you can see in the picture next to the desktop folder, which is also called pictures) it will be added also in Desktop, as if the two folder were now the same thing, except for the icon.

Comment: You can try the following and see if it works.  Start, Settings, Personalization, Themes, Desktop Icon settings.  Uncheck User Folders, close out, restart, go back and enable User Folders. Restart.  See if that helps.

Comment: While you are in "Desktop Icon settings", you could also try "Restore Default".

Comment: @John all boxes were already unchecked, except recycle bin. I also did what harrymc suggested, but it's still the same.

Comment: Try a Windows 11 Repair Install and Keep Everything.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11  ... If that does not work, your User Profile is damaged and the simplest (not only) repair is to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Fra There are two things called Location in Properties, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwU5A.png). Do you mean the tab (the one circled in red in my screenshot) or the one circled in green in my screenshot? If you click on the tab, it will show you a field with a location, that's the one I'm asking about.

Comment: @Fra From the second part of your comment, it sounds like the location of the actual folder (the one you can read in the Location tab) is C:\Users\franc\Pictures. Is that the case? If so, your problem can probably be solved by clicking on the "Reset default" button in that same Location tab.

Comment: @DonaldDuck . Both tabs (green and red) say that the directory is "C:\Users\"  
I already tried clicking "default", and that's where it says "C:\Users\franc\Pictures", even if I'm in the properties section of Desktop. I'm considering doing a reset. I bought this computer two days ago, so it shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: @Fra That's weird that the Default button resets it to Pictures. You could try manually entering C:\Users\franc\Desktop.